# How do I pass values from a Promise.all to .then()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have a promise chain that first collects contact objects and then processes the collected contacts. How can I pass the contacts to the .then() section after Promise.all()?

```
let collectUserDataPromise = []
allUsers.forEach((userId) => {
  //Collect all contacts
  collectUserDataPromise.push(
    dbRoot.child(`users/${userId}`)
    .once('value', (userSnapshot)=>{
      const userNodeData = userSnapshot.val()
      const contactObject = {
        alias: (userNodeData.alias) ? userNodeData.alias : '',
        name: (userNodeData.name) ? userNodeData.name : '',
        status: 'active'
      }
      console.log('contactObject', contactObject)
      //return contactObject
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> resolve([contactObject]))
    })
  )
})

Promise.all(collectUserDataPromise)
.then((contactObjects)=>{
  console.log('contactObjects', contactObjects)
```

My log shows that I have collected the objects correctly but that I cannot seem to pass then to the .then() section on last row in my code example.

Log from the .once() section

> "contactObject { alias: 'Donald', name: 'Donald D', status: 'active'}"
>   "contactObject { alias: 'Mickey', name: 'Mickey M', status: 'active' }"

Log from the .then() section

> "contactObjects [ DataSnapshot {
>       node_: 
>        ChildrenNode {
>          children_: [Object],
>          priorityNode_: [Object],
>          indexMap_: [Object],
>          lazyHash_: null },
>       ref_: 
>        Reference {
>          repo: [Object],
>          path: [Object],
>          queryParams_: [Object],
>          orderByCalled_: false },
>       index_: PriorityIndex {} },
>     DataSnapshot {
>       node_: 
>        ChildrenNode {
>          children_: [Object],
>          priorityNode_: [Object],
>          indexMap_: [Object],
>          lazyHash_: null },
>       ref_: 
>        Reference {
>          repo: [Object],
>          path: [Object],
>          queryParams_: [Object],
>          orderByCalled_: false },
>       index_: PriorityIndex {} },
>     DataSnapshot {
>       node_: 
>        ChildrenNode {
>          children_: [Object],
>          priorityNode_: [Object],
>          indexMap_: [Object],
>          lazyHash_: null },
>       ref_: 
>        Reference {
>          repo: [Object],
>          path: [Object],
>          queryParams_: [Object],
>          orderByCalled_: false },
>       index_: PriorityIndex {} } ]"
>    timestamp: "2019-09-08T18:50:40.259Z"
>    trace: "projects/xxxx/xxx"
>   }"

How can I pass all the collected values from Promise.all() to the .then() section of the promise chain?

Comment: I don't understand. You're logging the objects in the `then` at the end, asking why the `then` doesn't receive them?

Comment: Why `return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> resolve([contactObject]))`? Why not just `return [contactObject]`? And why is it an array?

Comment: Hi @rayhatfield! Thank you for the replies! You are right, I do not need to pass an array, that was purely for testing purposes. The large portion of the log is from the .then() section. I have updated my post to clarify. :) I got the same results passing "return contactObject"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `dbRoot.child('...').once('...')` portion of your code is essentially the Promise you want to store in the `collectUserDataPromise` array. This means you shouldn't need to create your own Promise as you have done (`return new Promise` etc).

Try the following and let me know it that helps:

```js
let collectUserDataPromise = [];

allUsers.forEach(userId => {
  //Collect all contacts
  collectUserDataPromise.push(
    dbRoot
      .child(`users/${userId}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(userSnapshot => {
        const userNodeData = userSnapshot.val();
        const contactObject = {
          alias: userNodeData.alias ? userNodeData.alias : "",
          name: userNodeData.name ? userNodeData.name : "",
          status: "active"
        };
        //return contactObject
        return contactObject;
      })
  );
});

Promise.all(collectUserDataPromise).then(contactObjects => {
  console.log("contactObjects", contactObjects);
});
```

Comment: The important step is switching from passing a callback to `once` to using a `.then()` call on the promise it returns

Comment: Many thanks Alex for the great answer! And thanks @Bergi for pointing out the critical difference! You are life savers! :D